# 700c to 26in V-brake conversion

Tags: brakes, wheels, rim-brake, conversion, size

I have search high and low and feel like I’m kinda close to the solution but..

does anyone know if there is some sort of adapter that facilitates my V-brakes to be lower, offering me the chance to put 26in wheels on (currently 700c)

Comment: Does the frame have disk brake mounts ?

Answer (score 6):

There are clamp-on V-brake mounts that could be added to your seatstays. My guess is that you would need to take a hacksaw to your existing brake mounts, as they would interfere with the brake arms.

The clamp-on mounts I've seen look like they wouldn't fit around fork blades; the simplest solution there would be to get a replacement fork, taking care to find one with very similar specs to the one you've got now.

What problem are you trying to solve by putting 26" wheels on this bike?

Comment: Before making major changes, it's worth thinking about how close to the ground the pedals will be. Will you be able to corner?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adjustable V-brakes?

For example, the Motolite by Paul Components [1] can maybe go down low enough.

[1] https://www.paulcomp.com/shop/components/brakes/linear-pull-brakes/motolite/